# Is there a different way of coding the select query in python psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

can't figure out what the error w.r.t select query here in python psycopg2 (postgresql query)

````
    cursor = con.cursor()
    postgreSQL_select_Query = """select ticker, timestamp, close from usstockseod u where u.ticker = %s;""" 
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query,[ticker,])
    close_prices = cursor.fetchall()
    c_f = pd.DataFrame(close_prices, columns=['ticker','timestamp','close'])
    return c_f```
````

Comment: What error? And why not use `pd.read_sql`?

Comment: 1) What is `ticker`? In other words is a single value another list or something else? Add information as update to your question.  2) You don't need to add the comma in `[ticker,]`, that is only needed in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Ticker is a single value. I am trying to learn how to write parameterized queries using Psycopg2 as the syntax isnt obvious, but couldnt find good sources of info.
The issue resolved itself when i re-ran the code in the notebook - so the prior variables data might have caused the issue in the first place.
Thanks...

Comment: You should have edited or commented on your original question instead of adding this as an answer